# How do I sort a list by date?

Tags: python, list, date, sorting

The date is saved in the format: 2012-09-28.  How do I sort the list so that the most recently published items are first in the list?

```
feed = []
for entry in entries:
        #code that saves title, desc, thumbnail, video, author, url, length, and date
        feed.append([title, desc, thumbnail, video, author, url, length, date ])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(feed, key=lambda x:x[7], reverse=True)
```

Comment: You get my vote for noticing that it needed to be a reverse sort.

Comment: If you have an aversion to `lambda`, `operator.itemgetter(7)` would work for the key function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky that the date is already in a format that's sortable. It just becomes a matter of selecting the proper field to sort on.

```
sorted_feed = sorted(feed, key=lambda data: data[7], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way to avoid creating intermediate copies of the feed:

```
def parsed_entries(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        # code that extracts fields from an entry...
        yield [title, desc, thumbnail, video, author, url, length, date]

feed = sorted(parsed_entries, key=lambda entry: entry[7], reversed=True)
```